# How do I get back to the village without dying?

Tags: a-dark-room

Every time I embark on a quest and leave the village the only way to return home is to die.  I don't know if I'm missing where the village is marked on the map or something.

Answer (score 6):

You can return to the village by going back to the tile marked with an "A".

[A full list of all the map icons](http://adarkroom.wikia.com/wiki/World_(Browser)), reproduced here in case the link goes bad.

```
Tile    Designation
A   VILLAGE
I   IRON MINE
C   COAL MINE
S   SULPHUR MINE
;   FOREST
,   FIELD
.   BARRENS
#   ROAD
H   HOUSE
V   CAVE
O   TOWN
Y   CITY
P   OUTPOST
W   SHIP
B   BOREHOLE
F   BATTLEFIELD
M   SWAMP   
U   ABANDONED VILLAGE
```